# Detecting typing in Messeges app using applescript?

Tags: applescript, messages

In the new Messages app, which replaced iChat, you can see when another person is typing:[image: bubble]

And i've been scripting around the messages app and was wondering if there was any way to detect when the bubble appears and in which chat through AppleScript. I have studied the script suite and have not found anything pertaining to it, so i may have to fall back to grabbing the packets and scanning for it. Any idea on how to detect this would be great, Thanks!